# valdiation in asp.net with input type button

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, html-table

i want to use validation control of asp.net, and want to trigger when input type button is trigger their is any way?

```
 <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" name="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_Name" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" ErrorMessage="name is requried" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
```

want trigger this validation throught input button

```
<input validationgroup="g1" id="Submit" type="button" value="submit" />
```

but can not achieve desire result

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the validation group to your textbox also. like this:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" name="TextBoxName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to validate a HTML control using RequiredFieldValidator. If you want to validate your HTML control client side only then you need to use JavaScript.

RequiredFieldValidator is used only for server controls.